# Linux script that captures mouse movement, and snaps a webcam shot: libraries?

Tags: mouse, webcam

I'd like to write a script that once run on Ubuntu, captures any mouse movement and immediately uses the installed webcam to save a snapshot to the desktop. I'd like to know which libraries are standard for this sort of programming.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer. [opencv](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/python/index.html) for python ([highgui](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html#createvideowriter)) takes care of the webcam, and [Xlib](http://python-xlib.sourceforge.net/) takes care of the events.

Use [python DBUS](http://dbus.freedesktop.org/doc/dbus-python/doc/tutorial.html) to send a Lock signal to a screensaver.